# C# save excel file with merged cells enabled

Tags: c#

I have made a code in C# which creates an excel file. Here is the code

```
    Excel.Application xlApp;
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
    xlWorkBook.CheckCompatibility = false;
    xlWorkBook.DoNotPromptForConvert = true;

    xlApp.Visible = true; // ensure that the excel app is visible.
    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlApp.ActiveSheet; // Get the current active worksheet.
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet2 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(2); //Get more work sheet if neccessary

    xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 1] = "Name";

    xlWorkBook.SaveAs(filepath + fileName, 51, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);  //For excel 2007 and above
    xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
    xlApp.Quit();
```

Now, the problem is that when i open this file again, then i see that the "Merge & Center" option remains disabled. So, when i opens this file through C# code, then i cannot merge the cells. How can i achieve that ?

Thanks

Comment: I recommend you to use EPPlus library for excel data manipulations, it's easy to use and it works faster. You can download it [here](https://epplus.codeplex.com/releases/view/89923) Merging example for EPPlus described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172488/merge-cells-using-epplus)

Comment: `new Excel.ApplicationClass();`? no `new Excel.Application();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is becuse you use `Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared`. This applies to many restrictions, see [here](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Use-a-shared--workbook-to-collaborate-b8207fe9-a613-483f-b804-0ca4658b0c61?CorrelationId=5b45c70b-98f4-4170-8dde-9c9d22c633f3&ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US). use instead `Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange`:

```
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(filepath + fileName, 51, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
```