# Merge the same values using in EPPLUS

Tags: c#

I need to merge the dynamically when my first column values are same in EXCEL Generation using EPPLUS. My column data was change when employees joining and termination. So, I want to konw How to dynamically merge if the columns are same values and I need to Highlight the each Total row only with backgroud color.

Am a beginner this was my first time I am using the EPPLUS. I don't know how to attach the sample excel file in this page.

I attached sample Excel file in this link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/merge-the-same-values-using-in-epplus.

Please help me to get resolved.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172488/merge-cells-using-epplus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this example to merge:

```
using (ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(filePath)))
{
    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

    for (int currentRow = worksheet.Dimension.Start.Row; currentRow <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; currentRow++)
    {
        string firstCellValue = worksheet.Cells[currentRow, 1].Value == null || worksheet.Cells[currentRow, 1].Value.ToString() == "" ? null : worksheet.Cells[currentRow, 1].Value.ToString();
        string secondCellValue = worksheet.Cells[currentRow, 2].Value == null || worksheet.Cells[currentRow, 2].Value.ToString() == "" ? null : worksheet.Cells[currentRow, 2].Value.ToString();

        if (firstCellValue == secondCellValue)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[currentRow, 1, currentRow, 2].Merge = true;
        }
    }

    // Save file
}
```

Comment: my requirement is quite similar but I want to check for columns for same value

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to merge rows when they have the consecutive values are the same (works to merge more than two columns):

```
    Public Sub MergeRowSameValues(ByRef sheet As ExcelWorksheet, rowInicial As Integer, rowFinal As Integer, col As Integer)
        Try
            Dim offset As Integer
            With sheet
                For i = rowInicial To rowFinal
                    offset = 0
MergeCells:
                    offset = offset + 1
                    If .Cells(i, col).Value = .Cells(i + offset, col).Value AndAlso .Cells(i + offset, col).Value IsNot Nothing Then
                        sheet.Cells(i, col, i + offset, col).Merge = True
                        GoTo MergeCells
                    End If
                    i = i + offset - 1
                Next
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
            
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Where rowIncial is the first row and rowFinal is the last row where do you want to check if they have the same value.