# Merge cells in excel using OfficeOpenXml

Tags: excel, microsoft-dynamics, epplus, x++

I am creating a excel document via `x++` using `OfficeOpenXml` Api, but I have no idea how to merge cells (Columns specifically). I have found how to do it with COM, there is a way to do it with the mentioned Api?

If the solution from [Merge cells using EPPlus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172488/merge-cells-using-epplus) is used, an `Invalid token '.'.` compiler error is shown:

```
CustTableWorksheet.Cells["B1:D1"].Merge = true;
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172488/merge-cells-using-epplus answer your question?

Comment: @FH-Inway No, invalid token '.' at CustTableWorksheet.Cells["B1:D1"].Merge = true; on .Merge point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using .NET libraries in x++ can be tricky sometimes, which is why there is documentation on the differences: [.NET Interop from X++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/net-interop-from-x)
([X++ and C# comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/dev-ref/xpp-cs-comparison) may also be of interest).

Looking at some other examples how the EEPlus library is used in [x++](/questions/tagged/x%2b%2b), e.g. in class `CustCollectionsExcelStatement`, I noticed that instead of the `Cells["address"]` syntax to determine a cell range, method `get_Item` is used instead. This is because .NET arrays have restricted support in x++ (see [How to: Use X++ Syntax for CLR Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/how-to-use-x-syntax-for-clr-arrays) for more information).

So I rewrote the statement as

```
CustTableWorksheet.get_Item("B1:D1").Merge = true;
```

Unfortunately, this causes other compiler errors. After some further trial and error I ended up with the following:

```
ExcelRange cells = worksheet.Cells.get_Item("B1:D1");
cells.Merge = true;
```

I don't have a source for this, but I think this is because chaining multiple expressions for .NET objects can cause issues in x++.

Here is my full test sample code:

```cs
using OfficeOpenXml;

class CreateExcelWithMergedCells
{
    public static void main(Args _args)
    {
        using (System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
            {
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add('Merged cells');
            
                ExcelRange cell = worksheet.Cells.get_Item('B1');
                cell.Value = 'Hello World';

                ExcelRange cells = worksheet.Cells.get_Item('B1:D1');
                cells.Merge = true;
            
                package.Save();
            }
            File::SendFileToUser(stream, 'Merged cells demo.xlsx');
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what the resulting Excel file looks like:

[image: Excel with merged cells]

Comment: solved! thank you, so helpful